# Can't change the width of Spinner inside TableRow in Android

Tags: android-spinner, android-tablelayout

I placed a TextView and a Spinner inside a TableRow but I cannot change the width of the Spinner. When I put it in RelativeLayout everything works fine, I can set custom width, wrap_content or match_parent but when I put it in TableRow no matter what I do it has a constant width. Can anybody tell me how can I make it to match_parent in TableRow?

```
<TableLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/logo" >

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/text"
            android:textSize="18sp" />

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/spinner1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:drawSelectorOnTop="true"
            android:entries="@array/items"
            android:prompt="@string/prompt"
            android:textSize="18sp" />
    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

For the spinner:

android:layout_weight="1"

This helped me.